# Scala: Create new list of same type

Tags: list, scala, copy

I'm stuck and the solutions Google offered me (not that many) didn't work somehow. It sounds trivial but kept me busy for two hours now (maybe I should go for a walk...).

I've got a list of type `XY`, `oldList: List[XY]` with elements in it. All I need is a new, empty `List` of the same type.

I've already tried stuff like:

```
newList[classOf(oldList[0])]
newList = oldList.clone()
newList.clear()
```

But it didn't work some how or takes `MutableList`, which I don't like. :/

Is there a best (or any working) practice to create a new `List` of a certain type?

Grateful for any advice,
Teapot

P.S. please don't be too harsh if it's simple, I'm new to Scala. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because empty lists do not contain anything, the type parameter doesn't actually matter - an empty `List[Int]` is the same as an empty `List[String]`. And in fact, they are exactly the same object, `Nil`. `Nil` has type `List[Nothing]`, and can be upcast to any other kind of `List`.

In general though when working with types that take type parameters, the type parameter for the old value will be in scope, and it can be used to create a new instance. So a generic method for a mutable collection, where the type parameter matters even if empty:

```
def processList[T](oldList: collection.mutable.Buffer[T]) = {
  val newList = collection.mutable.Buffer[T]()
  // Do something with oldList and newList
}
```

Comment: This and om-nom-nom's solution seem to do the trick, alas I can't test it in the original context at the moment, only with Ints and Strings. I'll give it a shot as soon as the project is runing again. :) Anyway, thanks a lot, wingedsubmariner! :)

Comment: @Teapot By the way you can use [scalafiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console) in case you don't have REPL rigth next to you.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I've seen your post only now. Thanks a lot, that's handy!

Answer (score 1):

There are probably nicer solutions, but from the top of my head:

```
def nilOfSameType[T](l: List[T]) = List.empty[T]
val xs = List(1,2,3)
nilOfSameType(xs)
// List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: This and wingedsubmariner's solution seem to do the trick, alas I can't test it in the original context at the moment (doesn't compile), only with Ints and Strings.

Although I'm a huge fan of Cookie Monster I'll mark wingedsubmariner's answer as solution, as his additional explanation clarifys the case a bit. Which solution really is better I can't tell, as I'm not experienced enough.

Thank you very much for your advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be empty, all you should have to do is:

val newList = List[XY]()

That's really it, as long as I'm understanding your question.

Comment: I guess OP does not know type beforehand or want to abstract this pattern, thus, he cannot hardcode `XY` as type parameter

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately I know the type of XY only at runtime. I've also tried a workaround with reflection-programming but I guess it's not the best thing to start with, learning a new language. :/